# Подморосило. В каком времени слово?

Tags: словообразование, орфоэпия

Подморосило это слово в настоящем или прошедшем времени? И как оно будет звучать в других временах? (А то моросило-моросит-будет моросить, подморашивало-подморашивает-будет подморашивать, а как со словом подморосило - не знаю)

Comment: Ваша придумка имеет объяснение? Каков смысл этого слова?

Comment: @shampar , я  не понял, что вы подразумевали под объяснением, но я просто задумался над тем, существует ли такое слово, загуглил и нашёл это слово в интернете. Я так понял значение слова подморосило - накрапывало

Comment: В Нац. Корпусе РЯ его нет, как и нужды в нём тоже нету. Оно слишком созвучно с другим, что делает его вредным.